# Spring Hibernate сохранение большого списка грузит одно ядро процессора

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-jpa

Есть entity типа такого

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
private class City {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

...

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Cityzen> CityzenList = new ArrayList<>();

...

}
```

В процессе работы кода генерируется `City` c большим списком cityzenList (порядка 200 тыс). Сохранение `City` происходит в `jpa` репозиторий с помощью

```
cityRepository.save(city);
```

При этом сохранение происходит слишком долго и mysql грузит только одно ядро процессора на 100%. Бросьте ссылкой или идеей, как можно добиться ускорения процесса сохранения. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Можно попробовать поиграться с параметром `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`.

Comment: Как вариант можно попробовать сохранить все `Cityzen` отдельно перед `cityRepository.save(city);`

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-session-batch

Comment: И измени тип генерации идентификатора с `IDENTITY` на `SEQUENCE` (в документации об этом говориться)

Comment: Тип генерации `SEQUENCE` не поддерживается mysql. `IDENTITY` и `AUTO` не дают результата.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, я бы не "удалял гланды через задний проход" - не нужно с независимой сущностью Гражданин работать через другую сущность Город. Во-вторых я бы использовал [пакетную вставку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50882952).

Модель должна выглядить примерно так (свойство `citizens` опциональное, можно не использовать):

```java
@Entity
private class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "city_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "city_id_generator", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city")
    private Set<Citizen> citizens;

    //...
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Citizen {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "citizen_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "citizen_id_generator", allocationSize = 100)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private City city;

    @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    //...
```

Здесь используется [SEQUENCE](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-sequence) для генерации идентификаторов. C IDENTITY пакетная вставка [не работает](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-identity).

Дальше, сначала создаем Город (или используем существующий), а потом вставляем новых Граждан с указателем на этот город:

```java
City city = cityRepo.save("Goodville");

citizenRepo.saveAll(IntStream
    .rangeClosed(1, 1_000)
    .mapToObj(i -> new Citizen(city, "Citizen #" + i))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

На моем компе 100 тыс. граждан сохранилось примерно за 1.5 мин. Нагрузка на проц - в пределах 25%.

Полный пример: [sb-mysql-batch-insert-demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-mysql-batch-insert-demo).